# How to create a cloud variable in Scratch

Tags: mit-scratch

All over the internet I see examples/tutorials in which they create cloud variables. But when I create a variable (I've used scratch 2 and 3) I get

[image]

But I would like to get is this:

[image]

I just watch a youtube tutorial in which was told that for cloud to work you have to be a scratcher for at least 3 month (I have an account for 4 months now). So what do I have to do to get the cloud checkbox?

Comment: Do you have a link to your Scratch profile?

Comment: https://scratch.mit.edu/users/scaljeri/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two levels (for normal users) of scratchers: a New Scratcher, and a Scratcher.

When you create an account, you get the status of a New Scratcher. This is what your status is now:

[image: New Scratcher]

Then, to become a Scratcher, there are certain secret criteria you have to meet. It's some sort of combination of having like three projects shared, having commented five times, and following a few users, if I recall correctly. Then you'll get the Scratcher status, and it'll look like this (using me as an example):

[image: Scratcher]

Basically - you have to participate more on the site to lose the status of New Scratcher. [Here are the requirements for becoming a full-on Scratcher.](https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/New_Scratcher_Status#Requirements_for_becoming_a_Scratcher)

Once you meet those criteria, head to the "data" section of blocks, press "create a new variable", and then tick the "cloud variable" checkbox. Note that unlike regular variables, cloud variables can only contain numbers up to 256 characters long per variable with a maximum of ten variables per project ID (trailing and leading zeroes are allowed), not letters or non-numeric characters apart from `0123456789.eE-+`.

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri It's so in case a person set on destroying Scratch doesn't overload servers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to become a "Scratcher", not a "New Scratcher".

Comment: I think that this answer was already given. But you are correct!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to sign in.It was a mistake that I also realised when I started working with cloud variables. Even if you have an account and it still does that, just verify your email, it will work.